# PhantomJs uses several TCP connections when loading one page

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, web-crawler

I used PhantomJs to crawl some websites and found out it open several TCP connections when loading even one page. For example, the following is my try.js:

```
var args = require('system').args;
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = args[1];
page.open(url, function(status) {
  var title = page.evaluate(function() {
    return document.title;
  });
console.log('Page title is ' + title);
//page.close();
});
```

I tried

> phantomjs try.js http://www.google.com

and found out it used 4 connections. I know calling "page.close()" will close all connections. But such issue may still result in large number of concurrent connections if I use many phantomjs processes. Does this happen because PhantomJs does not use persistent HTTP? Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds normal.

PhantomJS supports HTTP keep-alive (persistent HTTP connections), and has it enabled by default.
It is probably just opening 2 (or less) connections per server (as it is supposed to according to the spec), and that is what you are seeing.

To see what it's like without keep-alive, try:

```
page.customHeaders = { 'Connection': 'close' };
```